# adjust jQuery option via CSS media query

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

i've looked through quite a few jQuery / CSS answers but none seem to touch on my problem _
i used popin.js to create a popin at the bottom of a webpage which appears after the user scrolls down past 500px _ everything works as it should for large screen but i need to know how to reset the height for smaller screens and whether it's possible via a media query_ say '@media(max-width: 768px)'

the code from the popin.js library =

```
var settings = $.extend({
            target      : '[data-toggle="popin"]', // Target element
            button      : '[data-toggle="kill-popin"]', // Close Button
            store       : 'popin', // Cookie Name
            offsetTop   : 500, // Offset when to slide
            duration    : 400 // Speed of animation
        }, options);
```

how do i change the offsetTop option for @media(max-width: 768px)

thanks in advance

Comment: you could use javascript to check the width of the window if ts 768 or greater than 768.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me Rani _ if i understand you correctly you're suggesting i create a new javascript function which overrides the original when the device screen is smaller _ sadly i don't have enough JS knowledge to do that..... hmm create an if / else to control which function is used?

Comment: what would be the value of offset on 768 and below? @maik

Comment: @Rani 200 possibly? _ if i knew how to do it i could adjust accordingly _ presumably for larger media queries as well _ do you think creating an if / else which tests for screen width would work?

Comment: yes just like this one check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qtsk1zwu/2/ just change the value and set the value you want

Comment: wow _ that is AWESOME Rani _ i can't upvote you but many thanks for your help : )

Comment: just upvote my answer so its accepted as correct answer welcome mate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok here is the answer https://jsfiddle.net/qtsk1zwu/2/

```
var offsetVal = 0;
$(window).on('resize',function(){
  if($(window).width() <=768){
    offsetVal = 200
      console.log(offsetVal)
  }else{
   offsetVal = 500
     console.log(offsetVal)
  }

})
$(window).on('load',function(){
  if($(window).width <=768){
    offsetVal = 200
      console.log(offsetVal)
  }else{
   offsetVal = 500
     console.log(offsetVal)
  }

})
```